# how to catch particular data from complicated string content with conditions?

Tags: c#

I have a memory mapped file which is holding data of stock market. I am storing data like below:

`Symbol, Date, Open, High, Close, Low, Volume
AAPL,25/01/2019 03:00:00,153.55,153.9,153.9,153.55,821
AAPL,25/01/2019 03:02:00,154.2,154.21,154.21,154.2,966`

Now we want to get a list of close price from each line. Exactly we need like, if current time stamp is 25/01/2019 11:35:00 AM and condition is for 15 ticks then I need close price list from 25/01/2019 11:19:00 AM to 11:34:00 AM.

I am trying to catch close price using substring and split but I have more then 10,000 records so this will make strange.

```
string name = "AAPL,25/01/2019 03:00:00,153.55,153.9,153.9,153.55,821";
//name = name.Substring(name.IndexOf(',') + 1);
//name = name.Split(',').Last();
```

Comment: Define "make strange".  How exactly is your code not working as expected?  Anything that works on 1 record will work on 10,000 records of the same format.  What's the specific problem?

Comment: Hello @David, Like, If when I am applying code like below then it taking to much time for execution. I am also trying to implement PLINQ for all symbols at a time.
 
`string name = "AAPL,25/01/2019 03:00:00,153.55,153.9,153.9,153.55,821";
name = name.Substring(name.IndexOf(',') + 1);
name = name.Substring(name.IndexOf(',') + 1);
name = name.Substring(name.IndexOf(',') + 1);
name = name.Substring(name.IndexOf(',') + 1);
name = name.Split(',').First();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must split your task into two parts. First read and convert the file into an appropriate structure. For this you must create a class representing one stock data record:

```
public class StockData
{
    public string Symbol { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public decimal Open { get; set; }
    public decimal High { get; set; }
    public decimal Close { get; set; }
    public decimal Low { get; set; }
    public int Volume { get; set; }
}
```

Then create a method reading the data

```
private static IEnumerable<StockData> ReadStockData(string path)
{
    const int ExpectedSize = 15000;

    var stockData = new List<StockData>(ExpectedSize); // For efficiency. Defines starting size
                                                       // of internal buffer and avoids
                                                       // resizing operations.
    foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(path)) {
        string[] parts = line.Split(',');
        if (parts.Length == 7) { // Exclude empty lines etc.
            var data = new StockData {
                Symbol = parts[0],
                Date = DateTime.Parse(parts[1]),
                Open = Decimal.Parse(parts[2]),
                High = Decimal.Parse(parts[3]),
                Close = Decimal.Parse(parts[4]),
                Low = Decimal.Parse(parts[5]),
                Volume = Int32.Parse(parts[6])
            };
            stockData.Add(data);
        }
    }
    return stockData;
}
```

For sake of simplicity, I did not include any error handling. You might want to use `TryParse` instead of `Parse` etc. But it depends on the quality of the data.

Then you can select and analyze the data

```
var data = ReadStockData(path);
var start = new DateTime(2019, 1, 25, 3, 0, 0);
var end = start.AddMinutes(15);
var result = data
    .SkipWhile(d => d.Date < start)
    .TakeWhile(d => d.Date <= end);
foreach (StockData sd in result) {
    // ...
}
```

You can also completely avoid buffering the stock data in a list and instead use an [Iterator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/iterators).

```
private static IEnumerable<StockData> ReadStockData(string path)
{
    foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(path)) {
        string[] parts = line.Split(',');
        if (parts.Length == 7) { // Exclude empty lines etc.
            var data = new StockData {
                Symbol = parts[0],
                Date = DateTime.Parse(parts[1]),
                Open = Decimal.Parse(parts[2]),
                High = Decimal.Parse(parts[3]),
                Close = Decimal.Parse(parts[4]),
                Low = Decimal.Parse(parts[5]),
                Volume = Int32.Parse(parts[6])
            };
            yield return data;
        }
    }
}
```

The advantage is that the file is being read while it is consumed. It will also stop reading and converting the file as soon as `TakeWhile` returned the last desired record. However, if you intend to run several queries on the same data, the storing it in a list still makes sense. With the iterator method you can still do it with

```
var result = data
    .SkipWhile(d => d.Date < start)
    .TakeWhile(d => d.Date <= end)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you @Olivier Jacot-Descombes. Let me try it.